# Angular Subscribe Result Into Another Subscribe

Tags: angular

How to call navigator get current position value to a subscribe function?

```
  lng : any;
  lat : any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(r => {
      this.lng = String(r.coords.longitude);
      this.lat = String(r.coords.latitude);
    });

    console.log("4 lng = " +this.lng);

    this.dbService.getLoginData('name', this.lng, this.lat).subscribe((res:any)=>{ 
      this.listHasil = res;
      this.collectionSize = res.length;
    });
  }
```

My service.

```
  getLoginData(nama : String, lng : string, lat : string){
    let ilogin : Ilogin = new Ilogin();
    ilogin.nama = nama;
    ilogin.lng = lng;
    ilogin.lat = lat;

    return this.http.post(GlobalConstants.url+"getLoginData", ilogin).pipe(
        retry(1), 
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

On console 4 lng = undefined and 5 lng = undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are async subscriptions, you need to make sure the data from one subscription is available before doing another subscription. In your case the easiest solution would be to rearrange your code so that the `getLoginData` subscription is done inside the sub to `getCurrentPosition`:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(r => {
      this.lng = String(r.coords.longitude);
      this.lat = String(r.coords.latitude);

      console.log("4 lng = " +this.lng);

      this.dbService.getLoginData('name', this.lng, this.lat).subscribe((res:any)=>{ 
         this.listHasil = res;
         this.collectionSize = res.length;
       });
    });  
  }
```